# How can I test a documentary making multiple claims?

Tags: discussion

I would like to question the claims made by the film [Cowspiracy: The Sustainability Secret](http://www.cowspiracy.com/facts/). But there are so many claims made there, I'm not sure if I should post multiple questions covering the different areas mentioned or if one question to check them all is better.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single documentary makes many hundreds of claims.

(At least, they should, but we sometimes see links to rambling YouTube videos sometimes where the producers carefully skirt around making a testable claims, and you need to watch for 5-10 minutes to find one.)

Given that, it is unreasonable to ask that someone prepare an answer that addresses the research behind all the claims. It could go for dozens of pages.

(If you have a good answer for one claim and not another, it is also problematic.)

Therefore, we suggest posting each claim as a separate question.

As you are a new user, I would recommend posting one first to see how people react, and to get the hang of it, before posting more.

Comment: Thanks, that's the exact type of advice I was looking for! I'll do them one by one. Moving on to the next when the current is either resolved or stranded.